# Remove mention of beta version from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an Android app that I regularly update.  I just realized that the store listing still shows a Beta program and allows people to join.

How do I get rid of this from my store listing?  I've read through a bunch of 2018, 2019 stackoverflow answers and not sure how to proceed.  Maybe there's a 2024 clear answer.

Apparently some of my users have "joined the beta."  They still seem to get the latest production version but it seems very weird and confusing.

Some details and questions:

- In my developer console, I see "Release not live" under the Open
  testing track.
- I've read that "Pause track" is the wrong thing to do since it messes up people who have joined the beta.
- It's been suggested to disable all the countries for the Open testing track - but "Edit countries" is disabled (probably since the open testing release is not live).
- If I look at testers under the Open testing track, there's no way to see who has joined or how many.
- I see recommended to publish to the open track with no apk.  But some say this doesn't work and seems dangerous.

What seems to be the ideal solution is if I could remove mention of Beta from the store listing without disturbing any users who have previously joined.

Any guidance would be great!

Thanks,
Jon